# Simple Excel Chart

Tags: excel

I have this table in Excel:

[image: Excel table]

and I want to have a line chart with x: CalendarWeek, y: PriceAvg. So I select A1:B5, click on Insert->2-D Line and get this "chart":

[image: chart]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, is the "X Y (scatter)", instead of 2-D line.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, same result for scatter.

Comment: @RalfHundewadt I adapted my answer according to my result.

Comment: Thanks Dominique! The € sign was the problem for Excel. I copied the data from the Numbers App on a Mac, so the € sign was plain text.